# How to change the color of form child elements on form tag focus using css

Tags: css

Am trying to change the color of child elements which are inside the form element on focus. Expect input field none of the elements inside form tag are reflecting with new color. When I manually go and change it to focus in browser dev tools, it works, but not on keyboard tab press.

This is what I tried:

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <span>icon</span>
</form>
```

SCSS:

```
    form:focus{
     input {
      color: red;
     }
     span{
      color: green;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you are able to `focus` the form element you will lose it when you will `focus` on the input so you may try something like this:

```css
input:focus {
  color: red;
}

input:focus ~ * {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <span>icon</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pseudo selector `:focus-within`

```css
form:focus-within input {
  color: red;
}
form:focus-within span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <span>icon</span>
</form>
```

In June 2018, for IE 11, Edge and some older browsers, you'll need a polyfill. There's the PostCSS `focus-within` https://jonathantneal.github.io/focus-within/

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within